# What is mscordaccore_amd64_amd64_*.dll and sos_amd64_amd64_*.dll after publishing .net core project

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, publish

I have straight forward question and i did try to find some simple explanation on what those two Microsoft libraries represent. Only thing that i`m aware is that are needed for fully self sustained application to run on any platform and also that amd64 is architecture that initially AMD designed and Microsoft took over to develop.

```
mscordaccore_amd64_amd64_4.6.27817.03.dll
sos_amd64_amd64_4.6.27817.03
```

I also want to understand what this version represent and why it changes in my case on different machines when i do publish. (Azure DevOps and Local etc.)

```
<WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
<PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
<LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
<LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
<SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
<LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
<ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
<ProjectGuid>1f06a280-1fbd-4d32-938c-6f9d11c77789</ProjectGuid>
<publishUrl>bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\win-x64\publish\</publishUrl>
<DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
<SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
<_IsPortable>false</_IsPortable>
<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
```

Comment: sos dll is required for debugging and the version has to match to runtime version. Getting the correct files is hard, so it better to get them deployed to project.

Comment: Thanks for replay. I still don`t get version since my runtime version is 4.8.3761.0 and still produces 4.6.2.*
So you are saying this Sos dll is Microsoft's library for debugging environment for any executing process inside CLR?

Comment: Can you tell us the version of .NET Core? And what commands you run to see these files? `amd64` is the architecture that's also known as `x86_64` and `x64`. It was initially created by AMD (hence the `amd64`) but is now used by Intel and AMD to develop the commonly used desktop processors. Microsoft (and a ton of other vendors) make software that target that platform. Microsoft doesn't really develop the `amd64` architecture itself.

Comment: I updated post with Publish profile Information. Command that i run is standard dotnet publish with all this parameters

Comment: I see the file in this location: **"C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.2.6\mscordaccore_amd64_amd64_4.6.27817.03.dll"** So it is part of the older .net core 2.2.6. Current version is 2.2.8 and here the DLL is **mscordaccore_amd64_amd64_4.6.28207.03.dll**. So update the .net core 2.2 SDK

Comment: What I find out in my case is that until I do a Visual Studio update it doesn't change. Once I do any update big or small, the version changes.